# node-tesseract module cannot open file

Tags: node.js, tesseract

I am processing image to text using `node-tesseract` npm package.I get this error:

**{ [Error: Command failed: read_params_file: Can't open C:\Users\412366\AppData\L ocal\Temp\node-tesseract-c0734637-afb0-4e8e-92a9-46810d5c3237**

I could'nt find `node-tesseract-c0734637-afb0-4e8e-92a9-46810d5c3237` folder in my temp and have full r/w permissions.
I can run tesseract from command-line and get the desired result but not using `node-tesseract` npm module.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the package.? And show some basic code what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have installed the tesseract ( https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ )

2) Open the webstrom or visual studio as administrator and run the node application

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing via the [latest Windows installer](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=)?